# How to prepare executon plan for given sql query on a server with 4 processors (Oracle database)

Tags: oracle, performance, optimization, query-performance

4 processors means the query runs in parallel.

```
Select /*+ parallel(4) */ T1.A 
FROM T1,T2,T3
WHERE T1.A = T2.A
AND T1.B=T3.B
AND T1.C=T3.C
```

Tables T1,T2 and T3 have 4,8, and 16 partitions respectively.

Using nested loops,sort merge and hash join as available methods of join. How to create execution plan for above query? I am not able to understand when to apply sort merge in execution plan.

Comment: It's not your job to "create" an execution plan. Just run the statement and Oracle will do that. To *see* the execution plan use `explain plan`. Oh, and stop using that old outdated and error prone implicit join syntax in the `where` clause. Use a proper `JOIN` condition instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Hints for join operations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm#CHDGGCHC) are used the same way as other hints, for instance

```
SELECT /*+ parallel(4) USE_MERGE(T1 T2)*/ T1.A
FROM ....
```

Optimizer chooses join algorithm based on different criteria. There are many things to be considered, but in general merge join is used when optimizer mode is `ALL_ROWS` (it prefers nested loops for `FIRST_ROWS`) , both tables involved in the operation have index on join column[s] ( it may still use merge join even if you don't have indexes, but `hash_join_enabled` set to false or using hash join estimated as more expensive).

The query with hint `parallel(4)` may potentially allocate 8 parallel servers (4 consumers, 4 producers).

Comment: as  a_horse_with_no_name stated in a comment, it does not make sense to create an execution plan

Comment: @miracle173: Execution plan in any case is not created by user. Hints may influence how it's created, and in some cases hints are the only way to improve performance. I can't tell for sure whether hints give any benefits in this particular case; I just gave an example of how to make Oracle join 2 tables using sort merge join.